# jquery 1.7.1 cannot select span by intersection of class and id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select the downvote arrow by both class and id. So it seems that I can select the first attempt:
                        $("span#"+obj_id+".voteup").removeClass('voteup').addClass('votedup');

but I cannot select the second attempt:
                        $("span#"+obj_id+".votedown").removeClass('votedown').addClass('votedown2');

The code is pasted below:

Jquery

```
    $(function(){
        $("body").on("click","span.voteup", 
            function(){
                obj_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var theint = parseInt($("span#votesum"+obj_id).html());
                theint++;     
                $("a#vu"+obj_id).html('☺');
                $("a#vd"+obj_id).html('⬇');
                $("span#"+obj_id+".voteup").removeClass('voteup').addClass('votedup');
                $("span#"+obj_id+".votedown").removeClass('votedown').addClass('votedown2');   
                $("span#votesum"+obj_id).html(theint);                                               
                $.post(
                    '/vote/',
                    {'obj_id': obj_id, 'vote': 1}
                );              
            }
        );
    });
```

html

```
                            <span class="no_decoration">
                                {% if object.voted == 1 %}
                                    <span class="votedup" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                        <a href='javascript:;' class='voteup' id="vu{{object.obj_id}}">☺</a>
                                    </span>
                                {% elif object.voted == -1 %}
                                    <span class="voteup2" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                        <a href='javascript:;' class='voteup' id="vu{{object.obj_id}}">⬆</a>
                                    </span>
                                {% else %}
                                    <span class="voteup" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                        <a href='javascript:;' class='voteup' id="vu{{object.obj_id}}">⬆</a>
                                    </span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span style="color:black;">
                                &nbsp;<span id="votesum{{object.obj_id}}">{{object.votesum}}</span>
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="no_decoration">
                                {% if object.voted == -1 %}
                                    <span class="voteddown" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                        <a href='javascript:;' class='votedown' id="vd{{object.obj_id}}">☹</a>
                                    </span>
                                {% elif object.voted == 1 %}
                                    <span class="votedown2" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                        <a href='javascript:;' class='votedown' id="vd{{object.obj_id}}">⬇</a>
                                    </span>
                                {% else %}
                                  <span class="votedown" id= "{{object.obj_id}}">
                                    <a href='javascript:;' class='votedown' id="vd{{object.obj_id}}">⬇</a>
                                  </span>   
                                {% endif %} 
                            </span>
                        </span>
```

Comment: Are you duplicating `id` attributes? Don't do that, that's not valid HTML: ["There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Comment: It "looks" ok-ish (ID thing is an issue), but it would be much easier to tell if you use after-processing HTML (after template replacement and such). As it is no one can just run the code and see what's up, and there isn't obviously/strictly any reason it shouldn't work. A jsfiddle would be a bonus. Aside from that, perhaps try selecting by ID only and see if the selector contains anything? Also by definition there should only be 1 item with a given ID, and the results of that are....not entirely predictable, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID can only be used once on a page.  jQuery is likely always finding the first instance of the ID, which is why the 2nd attempt (adding the votedown class) does not find anything.